# Overriding Bootstrap's @breadcrumb-separator

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I thought it's possible to replace the `@breadcrumb-separator` temporarily, but unfortunately it doesn't work that way:

```
#detailnavigation {
  @breadcrumb-separator: "|";
  .list-inline.related {
    .breadcrumb;
  }
}
```

Isn't it possible to override a variable in a given scope? Or is the problem that `.breadcrumb` isn't a mixin?

Comment: Hi Jim, I see the `@breadcrumb-separator` variable in L15 of their breadcrumbs.less https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/breadcrumbs.less#L15

Comment: sorry, removed my answer because I misunderstood your question...not sure about overriding LESS variables within a particular div, but I'll see if I can find anything :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FYI I temporarily solved my problem by overriding the Separator manually. There you go:

```
#detailnavigation {
  .list-inline.related {
    .breadcrumb;
    
    > li+li:before {
      content: "|\00a0"; 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit shorter; here an example for ">"

```
.breadcrumb>li+li:before { padding: 0 5px; color: #ccc; content: ">"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 5:

```
:root {
    --bs-breadcrumb-divider: '>';
}
```